# Warning while resizing integer array

Tags: c, malloc

In my program I am trying to resize array using malloc function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int list[5],i;
    int* ptr = &list;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        list[i] = i;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%d\n", list[i]);

    printf("----------------------------------------\n");

    ptr = malloc(10);

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        list[i] = i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d\n", list[i]);
}
```

While compiling the program I get two warnings :

> searock@searock-desktop:~/C$ cc malloc.c -o malloc
>   malloc.c: In function ‘main’:
>   malloc.c:6: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
>   malloc.c:16: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’

My program is running fine. I can't understand why the compiler is giving me this errors?

Should I change my approach?

**Edit 1 :** And then how do I free the memory? should I use free(list); or free(ptr);

**Edit 2 :** Updated Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int list[5],i;
    int* ptr = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));   //&list;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        ptr[i] = i;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%d\n", ptr[i]);

    printf("----------------------------------------\n");

    ptr = realloc(ptr, 10 * sizeof(int));    //malloc(10);

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        ptr[i] = i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d\n", ptr[i]);

        free(ptr);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: list is an array on the stack, but ptr is a pointer to 10 bytes (should be 5 * sizeof(int)) allocated on the heap.

Comment: If you don't already have one, you might consider picking up [a good introductory book on C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: and how do I free the memory ?

Comment: Include the correct header - `<stdlib.h>`; and pay attention to your compiler warnings.  If it isn't giving you warnings, find out how to make it give you warnings; if it won't give you warnings, get a better compiler!  (GCC starts with '`-Wall`' as the most basic level of warning.)

Comment: how can you resize memory on stack by allocating memory on heap? copy the whole array to heap and then use realloc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't actually reallocating `list`.  `list` is still `5` bytes, while `ptr` points to the `10` **byte** array.

Do something like this instead:

```
int* list = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
...
list = realloc(list, 10 * sizeof(int));
...
```

Now, when you say:

```
int* ptr = &list;
```

You aren't creating a "reference" to `list`; in this context (not in general), it's the same as:

```
int* ptr = list;
```

This means `ptr[3]` and `list[3]` are the same `int`, but making `ptr` point to a new buffer won't make `list` point to a new buffer as well.  If this were C++, the syntax for declaring `ptr` the way you're thinking would be (I think):

```
int (&ptr)[5] = list;
```

In any case, you can't `realloc` an automatically-allocated buffer, anyway.  This won't work:

```
int buffer[5];
buffer = realloc(buffer, 10 * sizeof(int));
```

The `realloc` would likely cause a segmentation fault, and assigning the new pointer to `buffer` isn't allowed by C.

Finally, stealing from the other answers, you need to `#include <stdlib.h>` to use `malloc` and friends; otherwise, it'll be implicitly declared to return an `int` rather than a pointer, yielding warnings and screwing up 64-bit compatibility for no good reason.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, malloc allocates 10 bytes, but 10 integers are 10 * (sizeof integer) bytes.

Use 
`malloc(10*sizeof(int));`

Comment: DON'T use realloc here - you didn't get the original pointer from malloc!

Comment: Yes, you were totally right. Had he acquired the original pointer correctly, he should have used realloc, but he didn't really get the original pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The first warning is because you are trying to store a pointer to list, which is an array, in an `int *`.  You need an `int **` to hold a pointer to list.

The second warning is because you never included the header file which defines `malloc`.  If you `#include <stdlib.h>` that warning will go away.

You've got several other problems here you need to address, it seems like maybe you need to read up a little more on C.

Comment: No, an `int**` would not be correct.  You could use an `int (*)[5]` if you wanted a pointer to the array.  Either way, `list` and `&list` have the same value, and in C pointers of different types can be implicitly converted, so both have the same result.

Comment: just do int *ptr = list; Though in the code here there's no need to initialize `ptr` to `list` since it isn't used.

Answer (score 3):

To explain the first warning:

```
int* ptr = &list;
```

`ptr` is of type `int*`, but `&list` is of type `int (*)[5]` (that is, a pointer to an array of five integers.

`list` and `&list` have the same pointer *value*, but they have different *types*.  If you want to get a pointer to the initial element in the array, you should simply use the name of the array, `list`, which will decay to a pointer to its initial element in most circumstances (the exceptions being when `&` or `sizeof` are applied to the array).

As others have already explained, the second warning is because `malloc` is declared in `<stdlib.h>`, you need to allocate `10 * sizeof(int)` instead of `10` bytes, and you need to be careful to use `ptr` when you want to use that allocated memory, and not `list` (since `list` still names the original array).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler gives you a warning on line 6 because you are assigning `ptr` to a pointer of an `int` array instead of a pointer to an `int`. Replacing line 6 with

```
int* ptr = list;
```

will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

> In my program I am trying to resize array using malloc function.

I dont think you can resize an array which is allocated on stack memory. When you say 
`int list[5]`, you have allocated memory for 5 integers on the stack. Now whatever you do you can not make that 5 to 10. till your program dies that memory will still be there. You can not deallocate that memory.

Lets say you do something like

when you do `ptr = malloc()`, your list is still pointing to that stack memory where you have five continuous integers.

Lets say even if you do something like

`list = malloc(10)` [actually this should be `list = (int *)malloc(10) * sizeof(int)`] you have just changed the value of variable list, the original memory is still lying on your stack memory.